# html options displaying duplicate json output

Tags: php, html, json, duplicates

So, I'm facing a strange situation here:

I have a form, that form has several categories wich are loaded via Json.

The code  for the part of the form I'm refering is the following:

```
<div>
  <select>
    <?php include_once("php_loader/getAllCategoriesOptions.php"); ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

So far so good, then I have that php file:

```
<?php
$con = $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","XXX","XXX","XXX");
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES UTF8");  /
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE IdCategory > 1") or die;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]=$row;
  }
  print json_encode($output);
foreach($output as $json){
    echo'<option value="'.$json['IdCategory'].'">'.$json['Category'];
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Wich returns me the following output:

[{"IdCategory":"2","Category":"Hobbies"},{"IdCategory":"3","Category":"Tattoos"},{"IdCategory":"4","Category":"Trips"},{"IdCategory":"5","Category":"Esoteric"},{"IdCategory":"6","Category":"Books"}]

Hobbies
Tattos
Trips
Esoteric
Books.

So far so good. But when I include this on my html page it gives-me the following output:

```
<div>
<select>
[{"IdCategory":"0","Category":"All Categories"},{"IdCategory":"1","Category":"Technology"},{"IdCategory":"2","Category":"Hobbies"},{"IdCategory":"3","Category":"Tattoos"},{"IdCategory":"4","Category":"Trips"},{"IdCategory":"5","Category":"Esoteric"},{"IdCategory":"6","Category":"Books"},{"IdCategory":"2","Category":"Hobbies"},{"IdCategory":"3","Category":"Tattoos"},{"IdCategory":"4","Category":"Trips"},{"IdCategory":"5","Category":"Esoteric"},{"IdCategory":"6","Category":"Books"}]
<option value="0">All Categories</option>
<option value="1">Technology</option>
<option value="2">Hobbies</option>
<option value="3">Tattoos</option>
<option value="4">Trips</option>
<option value="5">Esoteric</option>
<option value="6">Books</option>
<option value="2">Hobbies</option>
<option value="3">Tattoos</option>
<option value="4">Trips</option>
<option value="5">Esoteric</option>
<option value="6">Books </option>
</select>
</div>
```

( I took this value from mozzila firebug - in the website itself appears only the values twice )

What can possibly be happening here?? I'm not being able to understand where it's wrong.

It might be important to note that I Have a simmilar php file running before and that php files loads every entry of that table - I suspect it might have something to do with this but I'm not beeing able to get the solution ( I'm querying the same table twice in the same html page to have different outputs, one gives me several , one for each category, other gives me several  as mentoned above).

Thanks in advance.

PS: As asked: here is the other php file I used before in the same code:

```
<?php
$con = $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","ZZZ","ZZZ","sametable");
mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES UTF8");  //é preciso meter isto em utf-8 senão não manda nada
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM categories") or die;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $output[]=$row;
  }

foreach($output as $json){
   echo 
   '<li>
   <a class="item">'.$json['Category'].'</a>
   </li>';   
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Can we see the php where you call that on your html page? That would really help.

Answer (score 0):

So, It seems that I found the error ( and it's a really stupid one ).

I thaught that there was no problem running 2 php files at the same code ( and it hasn't ) but I didn't know that I couldn't name the two files variables the sameway, so, $output from the first php was appearing in the second php file giving me $output$output as the result.

Changing the name of the second file to $output2 solved this issue.